# flutter desktop run executable file that locate in assest,

Tags: flutter, process, desktop

how do I run the executable files from Flutter desktop that also store in that app itself, let say if I made a batch file that echo hello worlds. the idea is I don't want the executable file in the app itself. the only thing that I can think of is assets. I want to run the file with Process. start or run. I tried the "workingDirectory" to assets dir but it doesn't work. Any other solution or maybe I do it the wrong way.

Comment: facing the same problem did you find any solution ??

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: @Nux have you tried asset bundle?. I'm moving from this issue by not implementing this related feature on that project but recently, I encounter with asset bundle. maybe you can trie it out if you still looking forward to it

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.run('C:/Users/<Ur User>/AndroidStudioProjects/web_view_test/build/windows/runner/Debug/installerX64/install.exe', [' start ']).then((ProcessResult results) {
      print(results.stdout);
    });
```

Comment: I bet there is a better way than this? or not.

Comment: yes make some node js code and compile it with pkg and call it from flutter

Comment: or lock how to creat pakage and create it with c++ and  invoce the function from flutter woth channel